# Использование диска с уже установленной системой в qemu

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu

Можно ли использовать существующий физический диск с установленной системой в qemu? 
Скажем, есть 2 диска, которые под линуксом видятся как `sda` и `sdc`. `sda` является системным диском, на который установлена Windows 10, `sdc` -- это просто файловое хранилище, где установлены программы.
Как создать виртуальную машину, чтобы она использовала эти диски?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как создать виртуальную машину, чтобы она использовала эти диски?

да как обычно. ну, разве что потребуются привилегии супер-пользователя для прямого доступа к блочному устройству:

```
$ sudo qemu-system-... ваши-опции... -hda /dev/sda -hdb /dev/sdc
```